# How to implement a spray paint tool for html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to implement a spray paint tool that would be triggered when the mouse is dragged over the canvas. The drawing part is easy but getting the stroke of the spray paint is the challenging part.

It should look like an a actual spray, with intensity increases if the drag stays in place for some time. There should also be a blur effect.

Finding an image of a spray paint stroke on Google might work but that would only give me one color how could I redraw a stroke image with different colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how much this will help you, however I found **[this](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/03/having-fun-with-html5-simple-painting-app-using-canvas/)** tutorial. They created a spray tool which I think is the effect you are looking for.

The actual [**DEMO**](http://sketchy.theburningmonk.com/) is ready to use too!

Comment: **+1** Excellent answer! I deleted my duplicate answer. Cheers!

Comment: I google'd "spraycan canvas html5" https://www.google.ca/search?q=spraycan+canvas+html5&oq=spraycan+canvas+html5&aqs=chrome.0.57.3594&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 First link :)

Comment: I also got the first hit with **HTML5 Canvas Spray Paint Plugin**

Comment: Demo doesn't work on nexus :(